# Editing Copyright Function in Footer

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to use this function in my black footer:

```
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';

function Copyright() {
  return (
    <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" align="center">
      {'Copyright © '}
      <Link color="inherit" href="https://material-ui.com/">
        Your Website
      </Link>{' '}
      {new Date().getFullYear()}
      {'.'}
    </Typography>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (

    <Container >
          <Header></Header>
        <Typography variant="h4" component="h1" gutterBottom>
          Instaride Web App
        </Typography>
        <Copyright />
      <Footer></Footer>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

but I need the color of the text to be white. How can I change this default function? If I change any of the colours, I get an error that

```
No overload matches this call.
```

Comment: How exactly are you trying to change the color?

Comment: Originally, it is ```color="textSecondary"```in the typography. I changed it to black. Doesn't work.

Comment: From where, are you importing the `<Typography />` component? Any specific UI library?

Comment: @evolon
```import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';```

Answer (score 0):

According to **Material UI** docs [here](https://material-ui.com/api/typography/), These are the only possible values you can use for the `color` property.

[image]

#### Now, what to do?

You can use classes to override the default CSS behavior

```
<Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" align="center" classes={{root: 'some-class-name'}}>
```

And in your CSS file:

```
.some-class-name {
  color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you do it with MUI styling,

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Container, Typography, Link } from "@material-ui/core";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  bg: {
    backgroundColor: "grey"
  },
  copyright: {
    color: "white"
  }
});

function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  function Copyright() {
    return (
      <Typography
        className={classes.copyright}
        variant="body2"
        color="textSecondary"
        align="center"
      >
        {"Copyright © "}
        <Link color="inherit" href="https://material-ui.com/">
          Your Website
        </Link>{" "}
        {new Date().getFullYear()}
        {"."}
      </Typography>
    );
  }

  return (
    <Container className={classes.bg}>
      <Typography variant="h4" component="h1" gutterBottom>
        Instaride Web App
      </Typography>
      <Copyright />
    </Container>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

I've also created a working sandbox for you: https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-haze-kbt0h?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark